# Weird data in reputation leagues

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

I was looking at the reputation leagues for this site, and I saw something a bit odd:

[image]

Notice that the number of users who have a reputation change of 10000+ is the same as the number of users with 10000 reputation. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're looking at the [all time leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/69/alltime/math), so the reputation change is measured from the beginning of the site. This is the same for other numbers (5,000+) except for those below 200, because, as indicated at the bottom of the widget,

> users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues